# python save image from url

Tags: python, image, download, urllib

I got a problem when I am using python to save an image from url either by urllib2 request or urllib.urlretrieve. That is the url of the image is valid. I could download it manually using the explorer. However, when I use python to download the image, the file cannot be opened. I use Mac OS preview to view the image. Thank you!

UPDATE:

The code is as follow

```
def downloadImage(self):
    request = urllib2.Request(self.url)
    pic = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print "downloading: " + self.url
    print self.fileName
    filePath = localSaveRoot + self.catalog  + self.fileName + Picture.postfix
    # urllib.urlretrieve(self.url, filePath)
    with open(filePath, 'wb') as localFile:
        localFile.write(pic.read())
```

The image URL that I want to download is
http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg

This URL is valid and I can save it through the browser but the python code would download a file that cannot be opened. The Preview says "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn't recognize."
I compare the image that I download by Python and the one that I download manually through the browser. The size of the former one is several byte smaller. So it seems that the file is uncompleted, but I don't know why python cannot completely download it.

Comment: Why can't it be opened? What error do you get? What does ``file <filename>`` tell you? Did the file download correctly or were you blocked by ``User-Agent`` or ``Cookie`` restrictions or similar?

Comment: Include the python code you are trying in the question please

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. I have provided more details. Thanks a lot. I wonder if it is because the HTTP request in python is different with downloading by a browser so python cannot bring me a completed image file.

Comment: It seems that requests is a much better module than urllib and urllib2

Answer (score 96, accepted):

A sample code that works for me on Windows:

```
import requests

with open('pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
    response = requests.get(pic_url, stream=True)

    if not response.ok:
        print(response)

    for block in response.iter_content(1024):
        if not block:
            break

        handle.write(block)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! I don't know why requests module could complete that while urllib and urllib2 cannot do that, but anyways.

Comment: It does not work for the following URL; any idea how to fix it? genome.jp/pathway/ko02024+K07173

Comment: @Cleb That's not an image

Comment: This saves the image to a folder, but when I open the image it says that windows does not support the file format, despite it being a simple jpg. Anyone who knows why?

Comment: @Parseval this can occur when you try to save a non-jpg as a jpg

Comment: How did you decide on what content size to use? i.e., what's special about 1024, or is an arbitrary value?

Answer (score 220):

```
import requests

img_data = requests.get(image_url).content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

Comment: @vlad what if we are not aware of the image extension from the URL but we know it is an image?

Comment: @MonaJalal you don't have to specify an extension, as long as you have valid qualified URL address.

Comment: `pip install requests`  if you don't have

Comment: Using '.content' after requests.get() is the key to save an image

Comment: It does not work for the following URL; any idea how to fix it? https://www.genome.jp/pathway/ko02024+K07173

Comment: @VladBezden - This saves the image to a folder, but when I open the image it says that windows does not support the file format, despite it being a simple jpg. Do you know why?

Comment: When downloading a webp, the files are corrupted somehow. Using ffprobe, I am told `missing RIFF tag` and `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: webp, none):`

Comment: Note that this downloads the whole image to memory first and then writes it to a file. If you want to stream the data directly to a file use e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549993/3782904) answer

Answer (score 37):

It is the simplest way to download and save the image from internet using **urlib.request** package.

Here, you can simply pass the image URL(from where you want to download and save the image) and directory(where you want to save the download image locally, and give the image name with .jpg or .png) Here I given "local-filename.jpg" replace with this.

**Python 3**

```
import urllib.request
imgURL = "http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg"

urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, "D:/abc/image/local-filename.jpg")
```

You can download multiple images as well if you have all the image URLs from the internet. Just pass those image URLs in for loop, and the code automatically download the images from the internet.

Comment: I tried this but I get an error: HTTPError: Forbidden. Do you know why this is? I'm using this URL: http://assets.ellosgroup.com/i/ellos/ell_1682670-01_Fs.

Comment: @Parseval, adding this code fixed for me (agent was needed)
```
import urllib.request as urlopen
opener = urlopen.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Chrome')]
urlopen.install_opener(opener)`

Answer (score 19):

Python code snippet to download a file from an url and save with its name

```
import requests

url = 'http://google.com/favicon.ico'
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 8):

```py
import random
import urllib.request

def download_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,100)
    fullname = str(name)+".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,fullname)     
download_image("http://site.meishij.net/r/58/25/3568808/a3568808_142682562777944.jpg")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for your contribution! Could you add an explanation to your answer what the code does and why it works? Thanks!

Comment: How do I add the headers for url in urlretrieve? I had a problem with images opening in the browser but not through code using urlretrive. I have tried urlopen but I don't know how to download the image using urlopen.

Answer (score 3):

You can pick any arbitrary image from Google Images, copy the url, and use the following approach to download the image.
Note that the extension isn't always included in the url, as some of the other answers seem to assume. You can automatically detect the correct extension using imghdr, which is included with Python 3.9.

```py
import requests, imghdr

gif_url = 'https://media.tenor.com/images/eff22afc2220e9df92a7aa2f53948f9f/tenor.gif'
img_url = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwXRq7zbWry0MyqWq1Rbq12g_oL-uOoxo4Yw&usqp=CAU'
for url, save_basename in [
    (gif_url, 'gif_download_test'),
    (img_url, 'img_download_test')
]:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise URLError
    extension = imghdr.what(file=None, h=response.content)
    save_path = f"{save_basename}.{extension}"
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: This seems like the most upvoted answer, except with extra steps, doesn't it?

Comment: The extra step is there to determine the correct file extension. The most upvoted answer doesn't do this. People were asking why the most upvoted answer doesn't work for all image urls. It's because you can't always assume that the image is jpg. You can't save a jpg image as png, and you can't save a png image as jpg. This is a problem when you don't know the correct extension beforehand.
As an example, try downloading this image and see what happens:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJT899RTIAkN3W4lte7HjXzt9sbeviVdNaiA&usqp=CAU

Comment: Fair point, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For linux in case; you can use wget command

```
import os
url1 = 'YOUR_URL_WHATEVER'
os.system('wget {}'.format(url1))
```

Comment: That gives me an empty image for the following URL: https://www.genome.jp/pathway/ko02024+K07173 Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Cleb That's because the url you provided doesn't belong to an image. Try it with ```url1 = 'https://www.genome.jp/tmp/mark_pathway1641220140108369/ko02024.png'``` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who is wondering how to get the image extension then you can try split method of string on image url:

```
str_arr = str(img_url).split('.')
img_ext = '.' + str_arr[3] #www.bigbasket.com/patanjali-atta.jpg (jpg is after 3rd dot so)
img_data = requests.get(img_url).content
with open(img_name + img_ext, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

## download and save image to directory

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
           }

img_data = requests.get(url=image_url, headers=headers).content
with open(create_dir() + "/" + 'image_name' + '.png', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

for creating directory

```
def create_dir():
    # Directory
    dir_ = "CountryFlags"
    # Parent Directory path
    parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    # Path
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, dir_)
    os.mkdir(path)
    return path
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to 2 lines? :

```
with open(os.path.join(dir_path, url[0]), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(new_url).content)
```

Comment: what are you importaing? os does not exist