# extract data from multiple urls stored in a column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, data-science

I want to extract data from multiple URLs, but the URLs are in a column of a data frame.

I tried data extraction with the code below but no luck.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen,Request
link = data.column1
f = urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
```

It shows:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'type'.

Please help with the code. 
Thank you

Comment: Look at steps in this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51393002/5265615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to perform the action on the entire series of URLs at once.

Try iterating over the items of `data.column1` and don't forget to dispose resourses using `with` in order to prevent potential memory leaks:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

for link in data['column1']:
    with urlopen(link) as response:
        myfile = response.read()
        print(myfile)
```