# Python requests downloaded pictures cannot be opened

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-requests

The code below can download the images into my computer. However, when I open the images, the following error message appears: "It looks like we don't support this file format". There must be something wrong with my code even though the file extension is .png.

```
import csv
import requests

with open('rlth.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(file.read(1024))
    file.seek(0)  # Rewind.
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    if has_header:
        next(reader)  # Skip header row.
    csvrows = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[0]
        url = row[2]
        result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open("{}.png".format(filename),"wb").write(image)
```

Below is a glimpse of rlth.csv:

```
    identifier                           link                likes_count    company
0   2293876619351464318 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_VfKG_BJl- 175     Ralph Lauren
1   2293779660171363517 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_VJHKth8S9 3263    Ralph Lauren
2   2293716498600285587 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_U6wC6hdWT 12617   Ralph Lauren
3   2293068067321995905 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_SnUIOhOKB 8430    Ralph Lauren
4   2293002309485390353 https://www.instagram.com/p/B_SYXOeBuoR 7452    Ralph Lauren
```

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url/30229298

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python save image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url)

Comment: The ones that both of you mention are from url, not from a csv file with a header, right? I am not quite sure how to adapt my code.. @Frank

Comment: You code already read urls from csv and get image content by requests.get(url). What doesn't work in your code is just how to save the image.