# How to receive an image file with flask_restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have two APIs written in Python with Flask. The first one sends a request to the second and is supposed to receive an image file (png). The file is sent from the second with `send_file("example.png", mimetype='image/png').` How do I retrieve it from the response? I want to save it when it's received by the first API.

Right now I have a code that is sending a .csv file. On the receiving end it has the following code:

```
result_file_path = os.path.join(constants.RESULTS_PATH, f"{analysis_task.id}.csv")
with open(result_file_path, 'w', newline='') as result_file:
result_file.write(Response.text)
```

I tried doing something like this with the image, but it doesn't work. Response.text is just a unicode text, to the best of my understanding, so how do I access the image file sent? There's no such thing as Response.image. I also tried to use `cv2.imwrite` on Response.text, but that doesn't work as well.

Plus, an additional question: In this example, the .text is read and then written into a file using Python's csv library (that is imported). So why did it have to be sent as .csv from the second API to begin with?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url

Comment: @oli Thanks, but how should I use it in my case? I don't have a URL of the image, I have it (or am supposed to have it) attached to the response.

Comment: Aren't your APIs working over HTTP? means are they web APIs

Comment: They are based on Flask, so yes, they work over HTTP.

Comment: Great, and if you're already returning image as the response (using image/png mime type) then you can use your APIs URL (which you were hitting to get the image) as your image URL and use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(<your API 2 URL>, 'filename.png')`to get image and save it as filename.png