# Python Program saves program downloaded file as "file"

Tags: python, file, download

I'm making this project for a course and I can't get my Instagram pic downloader program to save the photo in a usable format. Even if I give it .jpg, it doesn't help. Still says "It appears we don't support this file format" when trying to open the picture.

Been stuck on this for a while, I've tried other ways of download too but the downloaded file still cant be used.

Here's the code:

```
import requests
import re
import shutil

url = input('Enter Instagram Photo URL: ')

def get_response(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    while r.status_code != 200:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        r = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    return r.text
response = get_response(url)

def prepare_urls(matches):
    return list({match.replace("\\u0026", "&") for match in matches})

vid_matches = re.findall('"video_url":"([^"]+)"', response)
pic_matches = re.findall('"display_url":"([^"]+)"', response)

vid_urls = prepare_urls(vid_matches)
pic_urls = prepare_urls(pic_matches)

if vid_urls:
    print('Detected Videos:\n{0}'.format('\n'.join(vid_urls)))
    print("Can't download video, the provided URL must be of a picture.")
    
if pic_urls:
    print('Detected Pictures:\n{0}'.format('\n'.join(pic_urls)))
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
    dst = 'INSTA.jpg'
    urlretrieve(url, dst)

if not (vid_urls or pic_urls):
    print('Could not recognize the media in the provided URL.')
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Have you tried using a specific program to open the file?  What is the full name of the file after downloading? (Your OS may be hiding parts of the name including the real file extension)

Comment: I'm using Win10. If I dont add .jpg to the filename in the code, it just shows up as a file and the type as "FILE". Tried different means of opening it but no luck. The goal would be that it would just write it as a usable jpg file..

Comment: It could be that the image file is corrupted/invalid.  Try opening it in various image viewers/editors to see if they give a useful error message.  Check the urls in your `pic_urls` to see if they're correct and lead directly to a jpg resource.  Try other methods of downloading the image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url/30229298

Comment: Cheers for that. Got it working, it was using the original instagram url from the user input instead of the one leading to a jpg.