# Web Scraping Shopee (Import Image Url)

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape shopee product names, prices and images. However, I can't seem to extract the images. Is it because of the html? I just can't seem to find the class for images in dataImg

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

products=[]
prices=[]
images=[]

driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=laptop')

content=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(content)
soup

for link in soup.find_all('div',class_="_3EfFTx"):
    print('test')
    print(link)

for link in soup.find_all('div',class_="_3EfFTx"):
    #print(link)
    dataImg=link.find('img',class_="_1T9dHf V1Fpl5")
    print(dataImg)
    name=link.find('div',class_="_1Sxpvs")
    #print(name.get_text())
    price=link.find('div',class_="QmqjGn")
    #print(price.get_text())
    
    if dataImg is not None:
        products.append(name.get_text())
        prices.append(price.get_text())
        images.append(dataImg['src'])

df=pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices,'Images':images})
df
```

Comment: Add some wait prior to the driver.page_source it's not retrieving the values due to page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

You grab the source while not all content is loaded. If you wait a bit longer, this wont help cause only the first images are loaded, the rest of images will only be loaded if they come into view.

### How to fix that?

You have to wait a bit and than scroll in steps down to the bottom of the page:

```
time.sleep(5)
for i in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 350)")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
   
driver =webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')

products=[]
prices=[]
images=[]

driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=laptop')

time.sleep(5)
for i in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 350)")
    time.sleep(1)
    
content=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(content)

for item in soup.select('div[data-sqe="item"]'):
    dataImg=item.img
    name=item.find('div',class_="_1Sxpvs")
    price=item.find('div',class_="QmqjGn")
    
    if dataImg is not None:
        products.append(name.get_text())
        prices.append(price.get_text())
        images.append(dataImg['src'])

df=pd.DataFrame({'Product Name':products,'Price':prices,'Images':images})
df
```

**Output**

```
Product Name    Price   Images
0   [ACQ] Meja Laptop Lipat Portable    Rp51.990    https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/83a9e6e8ecad7a3db...
1   LENOVO Thinkpad CORE i5 Ram 8GB/ 2TB/1TB/500GB...   Rp2.100.000 - Rp4.200.000   https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/44fbc24f5c585cda1...
2   HP Laptop 14s-cf3076TU/i3-1005G1/256GB SSD/14"...   Rp6.599.000Rp6.598.999  https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/170a45679aa5002f1...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The website uses JS to load the images, to bypass this, you need selenium with a small delay. Here is the code to download the image src:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

products=[]
prices=[]
images=[]

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'F:\Sonstiges\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=laptop')

sleep(8)
imgs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_1T9dHf')
for img in imgs:
    img_url = img.get_attribute("src")
    if img_url:
        print(img_url)
driver.quit()
```

In order to get the image, just do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229231/python-save-image-from-url) using the fetched URIs. If you use Beautiful soup just because it runs in the background, [is here the soloution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53657215/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome-webdriver) for running selenium headless (in the background).